# Radial wave-function integration with mathematica

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions, physics

I'm new in using Mathematica. I wanted to do some integrations with the radial wave function for Hydrogen atom. The radial wave function is given by,
$$R_{nl}(r)=2^{l+1} e^{-\frac{r}{a n}} \sqrt{\frac{(-l+n-1)!}{a^3 n^4 (l+n)!}} \left(\frac{r}{a
   n}\right)^l L_{-l+n-1}^{2 l+1}\left(\frac{2 r}{a n}\right),$$
where $L^-_-(-)$ is the associated Laguerre polynomial. Now the radial integration comes with an weight $r^2dr$. I wanted to do the following integrations,
$$\int_0^\infty r^{-2}R_{n'l'}(r)R_{nl}(r)r^2dr$$
$$\int_0^\infty r^{-3}R_{n'l'}(r)R_{nl}(r)r^2dr$$
Asking mathematica to do these integrations just returns me the question itself. For example, I asked,

```
  r \[Element] Reals && r > 0 && {l, s} \[Element] Integers && 
  l >= Abs[n] && s >= Abs[m], 
 Integrate[
  r^2*(r^(-2)) (Sqrt[(2/(m*a))^3 (((m - s - 1)!)/(2*m (m + s)!))] (2*
        r/(m*a))^s*
     Exp[-r/(m*a)] LaguerreL[m - s - 1, 
      2*s + 1, (2 r/(m*a))]) (Sqrt[(2/(n*a))^3 (((n - l - 1)!)/(2*
           n (n + l)!))] (2*r/(n*a))^l*
     Exp[-r/(n*a)] LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2*l + 1, (2 r/(n*a))]), {r, 
   0, \[Infinity]}]]
```

Can mathematica do these integrations in general form? Or if not is there a way to ask mathematica to try out first few combinations of $n,l,n',l'$ and **tabulate** the results like following?
[image]
here, $\langle-,-|$ takes the values $\langle n,l|$.

Comment: Mathematica can't integrate product of two Laguerrel functions, even with known given values to the parameters. `n = 1; m = 2; l = 3; s = 4; a = 5; 
Integrate[
 LaguerreL[-1 - l + n, 1 + 2*l, (2*r)/(a*n)]*
  LaguerreL[-1 + m - s, 1 + 2*s, (2*r)/(a*m)], r]`

Comment: No. For given values of n,l,m,s Mathematica can do the integrations. Only thing I don't know how to do is to try out for different values and tabulate the results.

Comment: Note also there aren't only Laguerre polynomials but also $e^{-r/a}$ which you have missed i guess

Comment: `No. For given values of n,l,m,s Mathematica can do the integrations.` We must be using different versions. I just put the code above and it did not integrate it on my computer. And no, I did not miss the exponential. If it can't integrate the simpler one, no point of trying it with the more complicate version.

Comment: ```Integrate[
  r^2*(r^(-2)) (Sqrt[(2/(n*a))^3 (((n - l - 1)!)/(2*n (n + l)!))] (2*
         r/(n*a))^l*
      Exp[-r/(n*a)] LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 
       2*l + 1, (2 r/(n*a))] /. {n -> 1, 
      l -> 0}) (Sqrt[(2/(n*a))^3 (((n - l - 1)!)/(2*n (n + l)!))] (2*
         r/(n*a))^l*
      Exp[-r/(n*a)] LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 
       2*l + 1, (2 r/(n*a))] /. {n -> 2, l -> 1}), {r, 
   0, \[Infinity]}]]``` gives me ConditionalExpression[(2 Sqrt[2/3])/(9 a^2), Re[a] > 0]

Comment: This is not the same integral you posted in your question. In there you have `s` and in this you do not have `s`.  Try it on the same code you have in your question and you'll see it does not work. Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dvTlZ.png)

Comment: I'm the trying out for specific values of m,s,l,n. In the above integral in the comment I have tried m=1, s=0, n=2, l=1

Comment: Writing the way you thought I should be writing Integrate[
 r^2*(r^(-2)) (Sqrt[(2/(m*a))^3 (((m - s - 1)!)/(2*m (m + s)!))] (2*
        r/(m*a))^s*
     Exp[-r/(m*a)] LaguerreL[m - s - 1, 2*s + 1, (2 r/(m*a))] /. {m ->
       1, s -> 
      0}) (Sqrt[(2/(n*a))^3 (((n - l - 1)!)/(2*n (n + l)!))] (2*
        r/(n*a))^l*
     Exp[-r/(n*a)] LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2*l + 1, (2 r/(n*a))] /. {n ->
       2, l -> 1}), {r, 0, \[Infinity]}] gives me the same result

Comment: Can you give a source for your table? That should have an explanation of what conventions it's using, which may be different from what *Mathematica* knows.

Comment: The table is from a thesis not available online. The thesis may be using a different normalization because it's not doing it in the context of quantum mechanics but optics. So the table values may be very different in the case Mathematica does it. It does not matter in my case. I want to know how to create the table in the first pace?

Comment: Then, try this: `radial[{n_, l_}, r_] := 2^(l + 1) Exp[-r/n] Sqrt[(n - l - 1)!/(n^4 (n + l)!)] (r/n)^l LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2 l + 1, 2 r/n]; bk = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}}; Outer[Integrate[radial[#1, r] radial[#2, r], {r, 0, ∞}] &, bk, bk, 1]`. Note that I have capriciously set the Bohr radius to be $1$.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks! Would you put that in an answer so I accept it as correct?

Comment: @FaberBosch I'd recommend that you do so yourself. Self-answers are encourages in this forum, and JM may be too busy to come back and do so himself.